# What are the effects of an overexposure to solitary confinement?

Tags: social-psychology, sensation, sensory-perception, trauma, mental-illness

[Solitary confinement has been shown to be bad for mental health.](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/solitary-confinement-effects#mental-health-effects)

I was wondering if really long solitary confinement, [like this one](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/crime/robert-maudsley-solitary-confinement-prison-b2266575.html) are different to normal solitary confinement. In terms of effects and the proportion of them, not just scale.

---

### Minor and/or Related Questions

On a similar note, but not directly relevant to the question:

- Is solitary confinement mostly caused by sensory deprecation or specifically social deprivation?
- Is solitary confinement like (other?) mental trauma, or its own unique affliction?

Comment: The 2nd link you provide is not on solitary confinement at all. Have you done any research on this before posting? Prior research efforts can help focus the question. Also, SE wide it is discouraged to ask multiple questions in one post.

Comment: @AliceD Well, not in the legally culpable sense. But I don't know why that matters here.

Comment: Another related question: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/26758/7604